# SORTING C++, How can I display the name of the item?

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

How can I display the name of the item? so, the output is the lowest item price and also the item name. Is it possible to display item names in the sorting section?

[image is the compiled result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCsfh.png)

```
void bubble_sort()
{
    int b[] = {3800,1900,2700,2200,5000};
    int i,j,tmp;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
       for(j=i+1; j<5; j++)
      {
          if(b[i]>b[j])
         {
            tmp = b[i];
            b[i]= b[j];
           b[j]= tmp;
         }
      }
   }
   for(i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
       cout<<" \tRp. "<<b[i];
       cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: `b` is an array of integers, it holds only integer values, they have no name.

Comment: Make a `struct` like `struct book { string name; int price; }`, create an array of such books and sort it.

Comment: Aside: `std::swap` exists, you should use it.

Comment: @Caleth: By that logic, `std::sort` exists. This looks like an exercise, and then it can make sense to write something which duplicates existing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, some objects have names, but many others do not. In your case, the array object has a name `b`, but the array members are sub-objects without a name. You can refer to them by the expression `b[0]` to `b[4]`. If you look at those expressions, you see two sub-expressions (the name `b` and an integer) joined by `operator[]`. You can even have expressions like `b[i]`, where both sub-expressions `b` and `i` are names.

Also, there will be multiple expressions that refer to the same object. For instance, `*(b+2)` is the same object as `b[2]`.

Even for objects that do have a name, that name is known only to the compiler. Once your program is running, that name no longer exists (except perhaps in debugging information).

Answer (score 0):

You could associate the item name and its price together using a `struct` something as:

```
struct Stuff {
    std::string name;
    int price;
};
```

and then have an array of these `Stuff` and just sort it as a regular array, but use the price of each `Stuff[i]` instead to sort amongst them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Stuff {
    std::string name;
    int price;
};

int main() {
    Stuff collection[] = {
        {"book", 3800},
        {"eraser", 1900},
        {"pencil", 2700},
        {"ruler", 2200},
        {"pen", 5000}
    };

    size_t collectionSize = std::size(collection); // 5

    //Same logic...
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < collectionSize; i++)
    {
        for(j = i +1; j < collectionSize; j++)
        {
            if(collection[i].price > collection[j].price)
            {
                Stuff tmp = collection[i];
                collection[i] = collection[j];
                collection[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    //Print the item name and the price
    for(i =0 ; i < collectionSize; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<collection[i].name<<" \tRp. "<<collection[i].price<<"\n";
    }
}
```